# Load charts one by one

Tags: vb.net

How can I load Charts one by one. I have made a chart maker function and calling it on page load but I need them to load asynchronously, please help

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            ChartMaker(100288, Chart1, "Series1")
            ChartMaker(100289, Chart2, "Series2")
            ChartMaker1(100291, Chart3, "Series3")
            ChartMaker(100293, Chart4, "series4")
            ChartMaker(100295, Chart5, "Series5")
            ChartMaker(100278, Chart6, "Series6")
        End If

    End Sub

     Sub ChartMaker(Rnum As Integer, chart As System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart, Series As String)
            Dim Data As String() = Functions.runAnalyticsReportSample(Rnum)
            Functions.CredHolder(Session("User"), Session("Pw"))
            Dim split As String() = {""}
            Dim table As New DataTable()
            Dim colB As DataColumn = table.Columns.Add("A", GetType(String))
            Dim colD As DataColumn = table.Columns.Add("B", GetType(String))
            For Each line In Data
                split = line.Split(","c)
                Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
                row.SetField(colB, split(0))
                row.SetField(colD, split(1))
                table.Rows.Add(row)
            Next
            chart.Series(Series).XValueMember = "A"
            chart.Series(Series).YValueMembers = "B"
            chart.Series(Series).IsValueShownAsLabel = True
            chart.Series(Series).IsVisibleInLegend = False
            chart.DataSource = table
            chart.DataBind()
        End Sub
```

Comment: Scott Hanslemann has wrote an articel about registring and run async tasks: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

Comment: Might help: [Executing Asynchronous Tasks in ASP.NET](http://aspalliance.com/1778_Executing_Asynchronous_Tasks_in_ASPNET.all)

Comment: Do you want to be able to update them separately from the web page without refreshing the whole page? How about an update panel?

Comment: I did that with timer but the issue is, it will not show charts until all charts are populated